# Printing values from different elements of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list and I want to print 3 numbers from the list. Can anyone help? In this list, I want to print 4.9345,4.1756 and 1.1817.

```
list  = ['1 EURO = 4.9345 Lei', '1 USD = 4.1756 Lei', '1 EURO = 1.1817 USD', '3M (3 luni): 1.6%', '6M (6 luni): 1.73%', '12M (12 luni): 1.82%', '1 GBP = 5.7421 Lei', '1 GBP = 1.3752 USD']
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: what are your efforts ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
list = ['1 EURO = 4.9345 Lei', '1 USD = 4.1756 Lei', '1 EURO = 1.1817 USD', '3M (3 luni): 1.6%', '6M (6 luni): 1.73%', '12M (12 luni): 1.82%', '1 GBP = 5.7421 Lei', '1 GBP = 1.3752 USD']
```

for i in list:
if '1 EURO = 4.9345 Lei' in i:
print(i)
elif '1 USD = 4.1756 Lei' in i:
print(i)
elif '1 EURO = 1.1817 USD' in i:
print(i)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print the values from the first three elements of the list and if the format of each element is well-known then:-

```
data = ['1 EURO = 4.9345 Lei', '1 USD = 4.1756 Lei', '1 EURO = 1.1817 USD',
        '3M (3 luni): 1.6%', '6M (6 luni): 1.73%', '12M (12 luni): 1.82%', '1 GBP = 5.7421 Lei', '1 GBP = 1.3752 USD']

for i in range(3):
    print(data[i].split()[3])

myNewList = [data[i].split()[3] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: what if want to store these three values in a list?